# Is database in data.stackexchange 4 days behind?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I wrote a simple query to get latest posts

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Posts
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

and the result it returns are dated 2015-07-12 (today is 2015-07-16).

Is the data 4 days behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is: SEDE is updated weekly and the latest update is 4 days ago.

On the SEDE homepage, you can see:

> Data updated Jul 12 at 6:21

Comment: If you need real-time data you could use the [StackAPI](https://api.stackexchange.com/)